# Cannot use Git to Clone GitHub Repo onto my Pi

Tags: git

I have not seen my exact problem in the search so if it has been please point me in the right direction.

I have three computers that I want to be able to edit code on.

1. Win10 with MSYS2 MinGWx64
2. RaspberryPi 4 Bullseye
3. Pi Zero Headless Bullseye (SSH with extraputty)

I created the Repos on my win10 device and for the Win10 and Pi4 I can log into GitHub and see my repositories. I am trying to clone them onto the PI4 in prep for cloning onto the Zero. When I use git to clone my repos, it prompts for "Username for 'https://github.com':" 
However it then askes for "Password for 'https://@github.com':" which is not the mail I set up GitHub with, and does not accept my login password.
I have tried resetting my password and can log into the GitHub website from both computers, but still cannot clone using git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github removed password sign in to clone repos. Now you have to get a token on github and use that in the password prompt.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've been under the impression forever that cloning ***from*** GitHub ***to*** a local repo requires no authentication at all - ever. I think  your answer applies if you are cloning ***from*** a local repo ***to*** GitHub - but not in the other direction.

Comment: Git repositories that are private require authentication to be cloned. This is why the password authentication comes up.

Comment: Yes, but the OP doesn't mention his repos are private. IIRC, GitHub charges a fee for private repos???

Comment: Git clone doesn't ask for a username and password unless you are trying to clone a git repository. This is how I am getting the idea that the repo is private. Also, GitHub doesn't charge a fee for private repositories.

Comment: That was kinda' my point... it occurred to me that the OP might have been doing something other than what he thought. The question was a bit confusing I thought. But I see it's closed now, so I'll just wish him good luck. @mechmon

Comment: I thought this website was for sharing knowledge on subjects that you know about. Everything that you put in this thread is wrong or unhelpful. It doesn't matter if it is not specifically written in the question. Given that my answer has been marked as the best answer, it should be an indication to you that even though it wasn't in the question that my assumption is still valid. All you have done is waste people's time with your incorrect ideas which would take less than 30 seconds to prove false. Please can you fact-check yourself before posting again.

Comment: No need to get vituperative, Tom. I'm so sorry for wasting your time, and I promise you it won't happen again.

Comment: I am pretty new repos in general. Much voodoo and witchcraft is involved I think...

Comment: For clarity, my repos are private because I want to somewhat understand what I'm doing before putting anything out to the public... For instance, to not create a repo inside another repo, then decide to move the sub repo to a main level repo, with a whole new repo name and wonder why it's not working... LOL fixed.

Comment: I am sorry if my post appeared rude. However, I still hold the point that it doesn't help if on multiple occasions you present wrong information or irrelevant information. I understand that you were trying to help and for that I thank you. It is useful to have people offering what they think about the problem. However, next time focus only on the problem and make sure that what you say is true and helpful to the problem. Thanks.